# How to 'git-am' apply a patch created with 'git-format-patch --no-prefix'?

Tags: git, format-patch, git-am, git-apply

I have a reason¹ to create my git commits as patch files using git-format-patch with the `--no-prefix` option.

This option changes the patch output to not add the git-diff-specific prefixes `a/` / `b/` in file paths in the patch files. It allows tools like `patch` to apply the patch files without the need to pass `-p1` as argument.

All cool so far. However, it seems that I cannot actually apply them anymore with Git itself (git-am):

```
$ git am path/to/0001-patch.patch
Applying: <commit message subject>
error: <path>: does not exist in index
Patch failed at 0001
[...]
```

How do I apply them with `git-am` now, while maintaining plain `patch` compatibility?

<sup>¹ It allows me to use it as patch files in Bazel without custom patch commands, as you'd need to apply patches with `patch -p1 [...]`.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git-am` passes on a few options to `git-apply`, including the `-p` option, which does the same as it does with `patch`. Ie., apply such patches with `-p0`:

```
git am -p0 path/to/0001-patch.patch
```

It would have been great if `git-format-patch` was able to hint `git-am` within the auxiliary data of the patch file created, that it should apply them without the assumption of a path prefix — just like it can hint `git-am` with base tree information nowadays (see `--base` option).

Comment: First solution to this I've found which actually worked

Answer (score 1):

The `git am -p0` can be illustrated by its latest doc update, from Git 2.41 (Q2 2023):

See [commit 9b0c7f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b0c7f308a9a101deea3ddb359d1505d18f3cdba) (21 Mar 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a15b845](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a15b8451f2451fd212e0929b1bacb34de28cdc46), 30 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`am`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b0c7f308a9a101deea3ddb359d1505d18f3cdba): refer to format-patch in the documentation
>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Kai Grossjohann</sup>

> There were two reasons we didn't do this.
> As "[`git am`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9b0c7f308a9a101deea3ddb359d1505d18f3cdba/Documentation/git-am.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am))</sup> is designed to grok e-mailed patches, not necessarily taken out of a Git repostiory or even if it came from a Git repository not necessarily produced with format-patch, we didn't want to single it out as the "blessed" input producer to the command.
> Also, in the original workflow that "`git am`" was invented for, the user of "`am`" was expected to be a different person than the users of "`format-patch`".
>
> But this is a very safe change to make in 2023.
>
> Thanks to the effort by many contributors, Git ended up becoming a bit more popular than we initially thought it would be, and "`format-patch`", which took me a few weeks to pursuade Linus to take in 2005, seems to have become the de-facto standard tool to produce patch e-mails.
>
> Interestingly, the documentation for "[`git apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9b0c7f308a9a101deea3ddb359d1505d18f3cdba/Documentation/git-apply.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply))</sup>, which is listed in `SEE ALSO` section of "`git am`" documentation, does mention "`am`" and "`format-patch`" as two things that are related but different from "`apply`" in an early part.

`git am` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9b0c7f308a9a101deea3ddb359d1505d18f3cdba/Documentation/git-am.txt#L27-L29):

> You could think of it as a reverse operation
> of [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) run on a branch with a straight history without merges.

`git am` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9b0c7f308a9a101deea3ddb359d1505d18f3cdba/Documentation/git-am.txt#L278-L279):

> [`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply),
> [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch).